# Facebook error when like button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I get this, when clicking on the like button.

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=248753205242460&app_id=248753205242460&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D9%23cb%3Dfedecb848%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ff2ad19772%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26relation%3Dparent.parent&client_id=248753205242460&display=none&domain=localhost&locale=en_US&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D9%23cb%3Df99e53428%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ff2ad19772%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26relation%3Dparent%26frame%3Df2c40b1914&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?action=like&api_key=248753205242460&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D9%23cb%3Df458cef1c%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ff2ad19772%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26relation%3Dparent.parent&colorscheme=light&extended_social_context=false&font=segoe%20ui&href=http%3A%2F%2Fecommercedeveloper.com&layout=standard&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=true&width=400#. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
>   Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=9#channel=f2ad19772&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&channel_path=%2FDummy%2FFBplugin%2Ffb.php%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Dfe951f208%26 from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?action=like&api_key=248753205242460&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D9%23cb%3Df458cef1c%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ff2ad19772%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26relation%3Dparent.parent&colorscheme=light&extended_social_context=false&font=segoe%20ui&href=http%3A%2F%2Fecommercedeveloper.com&layout=standard&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=true&width=400#. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I dont know why I get that error, it could be because the code that checks the login is triggered..

This my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
```

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){          

          FB.init({
            appId      : '248753205242460', // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });   



window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            console.log('Sdk is loaded');


FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                console.log('GEtting logged in status');

  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    console.log('User is connected');
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
     console.log('User not authorized');
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
     console.log('User inst logged in');
  }
 });
};



 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        console.log('You liked the URL: ' + response.status);
    });

});





       </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you check that; is your facebook application's sandbox mode off?

Comment: and did you make sure you have a `fb-root` element on the page - `The JavaScript SDK requires the fb-root element in order to load properly and a call to FB.init to initialize the SDK with your app ID correctly.` http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: To tell you the truth I cant go into the facebook developers pages.. dont know why..wont let me. see update

Comment: I think I need to have my own app id... can it be the cause? it is my facebook name and not a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL` and `Domains, protocols and ports must match` usually imply that your http protocols are faulty.
Should you be using HTTPS for these calls instead of normal HTTP?

when i see these errors i usually test out if i'm missing an https somewhere...

Also see if your app has all it's secure URLs set up in the developer management panel on facebook!

Comment: lol..thats sound way way too complex. Thanks for giving me a clue at least. Does it also mean why it doesnt authenticate the user whenever the page loads? cause I want to check whether the user logged in or not

Answer (score 1):

> The other event that I am using is "getLoginStatus", which will show me if the user is logged in to facebook or not..

That’s not an “event” in itself – it’s just an asynchronous method, and it gets you the login status.

> console.log('FB.getLoginStatus: '+FB.getLoginStatus);

At this point you are not even calling the method – you are just stating it’s name. (I know, you’re calling it before – but this debug output does not make much sense.)

> I want to trigger edge.create

How exactly did you implement your like button? This event is *not* fired if you’re using the iframe version of the button.

> [from comments] I think I need to have my own app id... can it be the cause? it is my facebook name and not a number

Of course you do. Your user name is **not** an app id in any way.

Comment: Why my implementation of getLogin status is wrong and how do I fix that?

Comment: Of course that’s what you’re getting – because, _as I already said_, you are not __executing__ the method at this point, you are just referring to it by it’s name … and therefore console.log calls it’s implicit __toString method, and that just gives you the function _code_.

Comment: __Please go get an app id now!__ It’s complete nonsense to go and try going on without it, because you can’t even initialize the JS SDK without an app id.

Comment: i got the app id.. the even of the like button works, while the event of the logged in, still doesnt work

Comment: See update..the new error that i get..response.status is undefined